# Using an EndpointInterceptorAdapter to still set some content when there is an invalid header

Tags: java, spring-ws

So I'm starting with Spring-ws 2 and I am trying to process a request containing a header and body. Now I want to make sure that the header contains a certain variable so I implemented a EndpointInterceptorAdapter which is being entered succesfully.

However when it is not present I return false and my actual endpoint isn't called which is what I'd expect. However I still would like to send a non-empty response back to the user. Is there are a way to accomplish this or should I just check the header in my endpoint if I want to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in the EndpointInterceptorAdapter where isNotValid is a function that you will implement to check if your request is valid or not.

```
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

if(isNotValid(messageContext)){           
    WebServiceMessage responseMsg = messageContext.getResponse();
    SoapMessage soapMsg = (SoapMessage) responseMsg;

    soapMsg.getSoapBody().addClientOrSenderFault("error !", Locale.ENGLISH);

    return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```